# no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const pcl::PCLPointField’ to ‘const int&’

Tags: c++, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04
After git cloning "Handeye-Calibration-ROS"
`catkin_make` gives error.
I have added some parts of error

```
/usr/local/include/ceres/autodiff_cost_function.h:211:69:   required from ‘bool ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, kNumResiduals, Ns>::Evaluate(const double* const*, double*, double**) const [with CostFunctor = ReprojectionError3D; int kNumResiduals = 3; int ...Ns = {4, 3}]’
/usr/local/include/ceres/autodiff_cost_function.h:201:8:   required from here
/usr/local/include/ceres/internal/autodiff.h:314:9: error: no type named ‘Parameters’ in ‘class ceres::internal::ParameterDims<false, 4, 3>’
  314 |   using Parameters = typename ParameterDims::Parameters;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/ceres/internal/autodiff.h:347:47: error: no type named ‘Parameters’ in ‘class ceres::internal::ParameterDims<false, 4, 3>’
  347 |   Make1stOrderPerturbations<Parameters>::Apply(parameters,
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
  348 |                                                parameters_as_jets.data());
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/ceres/internal/autodiff.h:356:39: error: no type named ‘Parameters’ in ‘class ceres::internal::ParameterDims<false, 4, 3>’
  356 |   Take1stOrderParts<Parameters>::Apply(
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
  357 |       num_outputs, residuals_as_jets.data(), jacobians);
```

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h:880:100:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::getFieldIndex(const string&, const std::vector<pcl::PCLPointField>&) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZRGB; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]::<lambda(const int&)>) (const pcl::PCLPointField&)’
  283 |  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/visualization/impl/pcl_visualizer.hpp:82:72:   required from ‘bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(const typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr&, const string&, int) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr = boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h:867:68:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::getFieldIndex(const string&, const std::vector<pcl::PCLPointField>&) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]::<lambda(const int&)>) (const pcl::PCLPointField&)’
  283 |  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/io.h:586,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/io/file_io.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:44,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:70,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/pcl_ros/point_cloud.h:9,
                 from /home/level/ACobot_Project/handeyecal_ws/src/Handeye-Calibration-ROS/src/camera_driver/src/realsense2_driver.cpp:27:
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/impl/io.hpp:73:7: note: candidate: ‘pcl::getFieldIndex(const string&, const std::vector<pcl::PCLPointField>&) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]::<lambda(const int&)>’
   73 |       [&field_name](const auto& field) { return field.name == field_name; });
      |       ^
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/impl/io.hpp:73:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const pcl::PCLPointField’ to ‘const int&’
make[2]: *** [camera_driver/CMakeFiles/realsense2_driver.dir/build.make:76: camera_driver/CMakeFiles/realsense2_driver.dir/src/realsense2_driver.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2053: camera_driver/CMakeFiles/realsense2_driver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j24 -l24" failed
```

So can you tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Any solution please

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the errors there are these two lines:

```
from /home/level/ACobot_Project/handeyecal_ws/src/Handeye-Calibration-ROS/src/camera_driver/src/realsense2_driver.cpp:27:
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/impl/io.hpp:73:7: note: candidate: ‘pcl::getFieldIndex(const string&, const std::vector<pcl::PCLPointField>&) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]::<lambda(const int&)>’
   73 |       [&field_name](const auto& field) { return field.name == field_name; });
```

And:

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/impl/io.hpp:73:7: note:
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const pcl::PCLPointField’ to ‘const int&’
```

So I had a look at the package:
https://github.com/lixiny/Handeye-Calibration-ROS/tree/master/src/camera_driver

First of all, be aware that pcl library 1.10 compiles with c++ 14 (cf https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1638), but the CMakeLists.txt forces to use c++ 11 or lower:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
    message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()
```

To get rid of this issue, you should better force to compile using c++ 14, which is normally present on Ubuntu 20:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++14" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
else()
    message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++14 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()
```

I could see also that the code was made for Ubuntu 18 and ros melodic.
Make this first try, and if it does not work please put the whole error code.

Cheers~